# Resizing a UIView does not work

Tags: ios, uiview, resize, popover

I am trying to resize a popover UIView. The following is the code I'm using to make the clip:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
 [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
 CGRect box;
 box = self.view.frame;
 box.size.height -= 100;
 [self.view setFrame:box];
}
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

The self.view background is white. What do I need to do in order to clip the portion marked as 'X'. The UIView, self.view is the topmost view of the UIViewController.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller for the view, you can define preferredContentSize. Like this

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

*Ninja edit: Pre-iOS7, you would use self.contentSizeForViewInPopover